# Uploading icon and screenshots using google publisher API

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to use Android Java Publisher API. Everything is ok except the icon and screenshot upload using API.

We create a listing for particular language like:

```
Listing newUsListing = new Listing();
            newUsListing.setTitle(ApplicationConfig.OTHER_LISTING_TITLE)
            .setFullDescription(ApplicationConfig.US_LISTING_FULL_DESCRIPTION)
            .setShortDescription(ApplicationConfig.OTHER_LISTING_SHORT_DESCRITPION);
```

There is no direct set method for icon and screenshots. Anybody can pls help me figuring it out. The homepage says that it is possible to do icons and screenshot also but the sample don't show how to do it.
The only thing i have been able to find is this:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/images/upload

But don't have a single clue how to to do it with Java API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v2/java/src/com/google/play/developerapi/samples/BasicUploadApk.java) an example of how they're sending an apk, following the [API doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/AndroidPublisher.html), 
you should arrive to something like that

```
Edits edits = service.edits();
Insert editRequest = edits
.insert(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME,
   null /** no content */);
AppEdit edit = editRequest.execute();

Upload uploadRequest = edits
.images()
.upload(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME,
   editId,
   "fr-FR",
   "Your image type",
   mediaContent); // Your image as an AbstractInputStreamContent
Image image = uploadRequest.execute();
```

For the mediaContent var, [here's](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent.html) the link to the API

Hope that'll help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Like [`Listing`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/model/Listing.html) class you have already used there are such classes for images.

1. [Image](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/model/Image.html)

> Model definition for Image.
>
> This is the Java data model class that specifies how to parse/serialize into the JSON that is transmitted over HTTP when working with the Google Play Android Developer API.

2. [ImagesUploadResponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/model/ImagesUploadResponse.html)

> Model definition for ImagesUploadResponse.
>
> This is the Java data model class that specifies how to parse/serialize into the JSON that is transmitted over HTTP when working with the Google Play Android Developer API.